# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined" when trying to set environment variable for JWT token in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

Clicking the send button should create an environmental variable for the JWT token. However the postman log outputs an error:

[image]

[image]

Here is the javascript code that should handle creating the access token as an environmental variable within postman.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Access token was not empty"] = jsonData.access_token !== undefined;

postman.environment.set("jwt_token", jsonData.access_token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New test script for postman is

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test("Access token was not empty", () => {
   pm.expect(jsonData.access_token).not.eql(undefined);
});

pm.environment.set("jwt_token", jsonData.access_token);
```